# Rails doesn't consider modifications at compass.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, compass-sass

I got a weird problem. it seems that Rails doesn't consider any of my modifications at config/compass.rb.
All images are loaded from assets (exp assets/image.png) while they should be loaded from assets/images/ as indicated in compass.rb below :

```
project_type = :rails
http_path       = "/"
project_path    = "."

css_dir         = "app/assets/stylesheets"
sass_dir        = "assets/stylesheets"
images_dir      = "assets/images"
javascripts_dir = "assets/javascripts"
fonts_dir       = "assets/fonts"

output_style = (environment == :production) ? :compressed : :expanded
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the Rails server.

Files in `config` are loaded at startup, so the server needs to be fully restarted for the application to reflect the changes.